# TPM TSS middleware PYTSS Import Error - undefined symbol: Esys_MAC_Start_Async

Tags: python, linux, pip, tpm

I have installed tpm2_pytss and tried to run the tests present in [their repo](https://github.com/tpm2-software/tpm2-pytss/tree/master/test).

When I run any of those tests I always get the same error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/xxxxxxxx/thesis/playground/quote.py", line 5, in <module>
    from tpm2_pytss import *
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/dist-packages/tpm2_pytss/__init__.py", line 2, in <module>
    from .ESAPI import ESAPI
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/dist-packages/tpm2_pytss/ESAPI.py", line 2, in <module>
    from .types import *
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/dist-packages/tpm2_pytss/types.py", line 12, in <module>
    from ._libtpm2_pytss import ffi, lib
ImportError: /usr/local/lib/python3.9/dist-packages/tpm2_pytss/_libtpm2_pytss.abi3.so: undefined symbol: Esys_MAC_Start_Async
```

(TPM is working, tpm2_tools is working)

I installed the APIs, it was a requirement of pytss installation. I ran the install with pip and solved all dependency problems (including the missing esapi API package).

Answer (score 0):

This happens when the headers for the C library are newer than the library being linked too. This usually happens when there are multiple shared libraries installed and the older version is first in the linking search path.

On a lot of distros, the tpm2-tss packages are installed as dependencies to core things, so you can often times end up with multiples installed with the package manager one typically being the older one.

For more details see:

- https://github.com/tpm2-software/tpm2-pytss/issues/392